# Is it possible to show custom icons in the Scripts menu?

Tags: macos, applescript, script, menu-bar

You know that "scripts" menu you can show in the right side of the menu bar? It's very useful. I'm talking about this menu:

[image: Menu Bar]

I've set some custom icons for the files in the scripts folder using the Get Info window, but these icons aren't showing up in the menu. Is this something that will automatically show up next time I reboot, is there some hidden setting I need to change, or is this just not (yet) possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, but [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) does seem to use custom icons in the menu:

[image]

Comment: Yes, if you make your own app you can choose the icon that's displayed.